# Palindrome stuck

Tags: java

A palindrome is a string that you can read backwards and have 
the same chars in the same order as the original string, like: "gig".

I'm trying to check it in the code below, but it returns "false" even when it should be true. Why?

```
public class Palindrome {
    public static boolean PalindromeChecker(String s) {
        int sum = 0;
        StringBuffer revStr = new StringBuffer(s);
        revStr.reverse();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            for (int k = 0; k < revStr.length(); k++)
                if (s.charAt(i) == revStr.charAt(k)) {
                    sum++;
                }
                if (sum == s.length()) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This logic is extremely strange. Why are you using nested for loops? You can do this in a single line for String `s1`: `return s1.equals(new StringBuffer(s1).reverse().toString());`

Comment: You can check only the first half (half + 1 if odd), no need to go to the end of the word

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `revStr = revStr.reverse();`. At the moment you're discarding the return of `reverse`.

Then use `.equals` to compare equality on the original and reverse.

Perhaps a more efficient approach would be on the lines of the `.charAt` approach you're attempting, but get the simpler case working first.

Comment: `revStr = revStr.reverse();` is still a Buffer object and if compared to String it will always return FALSE

Answer (score 0):

No need for a nested loop here. By having

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        for (int k = 0; k < revStr.length(); k++) ...
```

You are comparing the first letter of s to every letter in revStr, then the second letter of s to every letter in revStr, etc. Try using a single loop instead:

```
public static boolean PalindromeChecker(String s) {
     int sum = 0;
     StringBuffer revStr = new StringBuffer(s);
     revStr.reverse();

     for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
          if (s.charAt(i) == revStr.charAt(k)) {
               sum++;
          }
     if (sum == s.length()) {
          return true;
     } else {
          return false;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way with a while loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(palindromeChecker("gig"));
    System.out.println(palindromeChecker("hello"));
    System.out.println(palindromeChecker("racecar"));
    System.out.println(palindromeChecker("12345678987654321"));
    System.out.println(palindromeChecker("palindromechecker"));
}

public static boolean palindromeChecker(String s) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = s.length() - 1;

    while (start < end) {
        if (s.charAt(start) != s.charAt(end)) {
            return false;
        }
        start++;
        end--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Results:

```
true
false
true
true
false
```